# Subir y bajar volumen de un canal audio con los botones fisicos en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, audio-manager

Me gustaría sincronizar los botones físicos de subir y bajar volumen sincronizado con un canal de audio especifico.

Que al pulsar se muestre el dialogo de la imagen, con el icono la seekbar y aumente o disminuye el volumen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

**Solucionado!**

Después de la respuesta del compañero @Jorgesys me he puesto a investigar más la posibilidades de los FLAGS del AudioManager.

Con la bandera `FLAG_SHOW_UI` se puede mostrar el Toast del sistema con la barra deslizante para aumentar o disminuir el volumen.

**Para el canal por defecto**

Sin especificar canal de audio del volumen, obtiene por defecto el establecido del sistema:

Para subir:
`audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);`

Para bajar
`audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);`

**Para un canal especifico**

Para asignar al canal de audio especifico, se usa el método `adjustStreamVolume(canal_de_audio,...)`

```
int streamType = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;
```

Para subir el volumen del canal de música:

```
audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(streamType,
        AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

Para bajar el volumen del canal de música:

```
audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(streamType,
        AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

**Código final**

```
private int streamType = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;
...
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)){
        audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(streamType,
                AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
    }else if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)){
        audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(streamType,
                AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
    }
    return true; // super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Ohhhh FLAG_SHOW_UI  para mostrar el control, eso lo desconocía!

Answer (score 1):

Una aproximación es detectar una acción en los botones para modificar el volumen y usar la clase [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)){
        Log.i(TAG, "VOLUME UP!");
        audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
    }else if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)){
        Log.i(TAG, "VOLUME DOWN!");
        audioManager.adjustVolume(AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: voy a investigar mas a fondo que creo que mas o menos ya lo tengo.

Comment: Solventado con audioManager.adjustStreamVolume y FLAG_SHOW_UI